# Xfce power manager warns HAL daemon is not running, no keyboard on startup on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, grub, hal

I changed my grub boot options to add "vga=0x323" to them to resolve some issues with corrupted display during startup/shutdown on my laptop.

The next time I booted the system up, I got a warning over the login screen saying

> Xfce Power Manager
>
> HAL Daemon not running

The keyboard and mouse are unresponsive. After a minute or so, they start to work and the system functions as normal.

How can I solve this?

Comment: does the issue go away if you boot without the "vga=0x323" option?

Comment: @quack - No, it went away about two weeks later after installing some updates.

Comment: you should post that as an answer instead of accepting an incorrect (or at least unverifiable) answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A system update, about two weeks after posting this question, solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

So apparently this problem is in some way related to the CD drive. If you have a CD in the drive then try removing it. I have no idea why this would make any difference, but it works for me, no CD, no error. Obviously this isn't a real fix, but it's an easy work around until the real problem is found and fixed.

Comment: This worked for me. Cloned a drive, and the new drive gave an error if the LiveCD I used to clone it with was still in the drive. Removed and all was well